# Can i implement custom authorization in NATS.io?

Tags: authorization, nats.io

How can i implement custom authorization in NATS.io, not through NATS accounts? For example, on a new NATS connection, it contacts a server connected to it, which is marked as an authorization handler. Or implement authorization on another server and somehow associate the token with the nats server?

If I already have a database with accounts and an authorization server, how can I match this with the NATS server?

Comment: This question is definitely revelant.

Comment: I thought about doing it by creating a unique subject prefix for each user, and having that prefix in my users database. But it looks like this would allow wiretapping by wildcard: https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/issues/2667

Answer (score 1):

As of NATS v2.10.0 you can do custom auth using [Auth Callout](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/auth_callout)

> Auth Callout is an opt-in extension for delegating client authentication and authorization to an application-defined NATS service.

With this you can implement your authentication as a regular NATS service and NATS will call your service to authenticate the user.

There is a go example in the above link and I have made two nodejs examples:

This is just a port of the go example: https://github.com/jonaskello/nats-auth-callout-cli-service

And this shows one approach to doing dynamic authz: https://github.com/jonaskello/nats-chat